# running python3, using python2 code, I changed httplib to http.client, ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x

```css
        if attr[:12] == '_Request__r_':
            name = attr[12:]
            if hasattr(Request, 'get_' + name):
                getattr(self, 'get_' + name)()
                return getattr(self, attr)
        raise AttributeError, attr

    def get_method(self):
        if self.has_data():
            return "POST"
        else:
            return "GET"
```

```css
    raise AttributeError, attr
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this error?
As you can see above I have added the lines of code giving me an error.

Comment: Looking at documentation for how to raise Exceptions in python 3 (https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) as compared to python 2 (https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) you can how the specification has changed. There will be many such changes necessary and tools such as 2to3 as suggested by @Mark can go a long way to making this transition easier.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [2to3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html?highlight=raise#2to3fixer-raise):

> **raise**
>   Converts raise E, V to raise E(V), and raise E, V, T to raise E(V).with_traceback(T). If E is a tuple, the translation will be incorrect because substituting tuples for exceptions has been removed in Python 3.

So it should be:

```
raise AttributeError(attr)
```

Comment: Sorry I am not good at converting python2 to python3 code can you convert this as well?    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @John Why not run the 2to3 script to port your code?  The link is in my answer.  In that case it is just `raise ValueError("unknown url type: %s" % self.__original")`.

Comment: thank you, Does 2to3 automatically do this? Or do I have to go in and make the changes?

Comment: @John Yes, read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html).

Comment: Sorry I went ahead and read through the documentation. I am having another error it's saying I am missing the module mimetools